# Edit an ASCII encoded text file containing binary portions

Tags: powershell

With Powershell, I want to edit a file using :

```
Get-Content $inputFile | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Replace("|Foo;","|Bar;")
} | Out-File $outputFile
```

This file is ASCII encoded but contains **binary portions**

Doing the same replacement with Notepad++ works !

Comparing the inputFile and the outputFile with Notepad++ I have some changes I didn't want :

- The output file length (char count) has growed from the binary portion row count
- Before the change Notepad++ detect the End Of Line as "UNIX", after as Dos\Windows (But the file use CRLF = Windows EOL)
- In the binary portions, Notepad++ shows "CR" or "LF" EOL before transformation, and "CRLF" EOL

So it's clear that Powershell transforms some binary characters to windows End Of Line.

How to avoid it ?

Before the transformation:
[image: Before the transformation]

After the transformation:
[image: After the transformation]

Comment: Use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText`: [Powershell command to replace a chunk of text in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5386998)

Comment: @wOxxOm Doing `[IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile) > $outputFile` kills my binary part

Comment: Same problem with `[IO.File]::WriteAllText($outputFile,[IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile))`. Powershell change the binary part, and the file becames bigger twice.

Comment: OK I have the solution : ReadAllText and WriteAllText have an additional argument encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @wOxxOm who gave me the solution :

```
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText(`
        $outputFile, `
        [IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile,[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")).Replace("|Foo;","|Bar;"),`
        [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
    )
```

Edited taking account of @TomBlodget comment.

Comment: Almost. But it's better to use [`[Text.Encoding]::Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) that works in this case as it treats each file byte as a character and correctly recognizes ASCII characters in code range 32-127. Anything outside this range will have incorrect *internal* representation, but will be correctly transformed back and written in the output file since we're using the same encoding we used for reading.

Comment: You shouldn't use Default because you don't know what it is. It could be an encoding that doesn't allow arbitrary sequences of all 256 byte values. Use an encoding that matches ASCII for byte values 0-127 and also allows values 128-255 and allows them all in any sequence. Here's probably the best known: `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")`